# How to fix issues with A-Frame's <a-scene>&<a-videosphere> going white or having skewed perspective

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, three.js, aframe

I'm utilizing A-Frame in Vue 3 to show a videosphere.

The videosphere is shown conditionally with a v-show, and also can have its height/width dynamically set based on different variables or inputs (e.g. a slider).

There are two issues that I have seen.

1. The scene / videosphere goes completely white. This typically happens when the scene is hidden with `v-show='false'` and then the screen is moved (e.g. mobile screen drag / overscroll) or window is made dragged to be narrower. When I go back to activate the scene / videosphere with `v-show='true'` it is blank/white. When I inspect the html, it looks like the videosphere may be 0x0, however its computed width/height appear correct.

I can reset the view to get it working again by

- Desktop: Resize the browser window | Enter then Exit VR Mode.
- Mobile: Rotate into landscape mode then back to portrait.

2. On initial load the video in the videosphere appears to be either too narrow or too fat.

This is also resolved via the same fixes.

Is there a likely cause to these issues?
Are there any ways that I could cause the scene / videosphere to reset programmatically?

Things I've tried that don't work:
A. Redraw AFrame
Watch for when I v-show=true
try to force redraw
`AFRAME.scenes[0].render();`

Result: No noticeable effect.

B. Fake a resize event
`window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));`

Result: No noticeable effect

C. Try to resize windows:

```
function resizeWindow() {
  const originalWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const originalHeight = window.innerHeight;

  // Resize the window by 1 pixel
  window.resizeBy(1, 0);

  // Restore the original size after a short delay
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.resizeTo(originalWidth, originalHeight);
  }, 100); // Adjust the delay time as needed
}
```

D. Try to change the size of the scene/videosphere when v-show=true.
Result: Would see the them resize (when I added a delay), but would not not fix issues, would still be blank or skewed.

Edit: I have confirmed that this is unrelated to Vue:
Here is a native Javascript reproduction of the issue:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/superb-swamp-deal